# Tracking a target using ML agents

Tags: unity, machine-learning

I'm studying ML Agents in Unity and I'm looking at [this example from the official Unity repository](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/tree/develop/Project/Assets/ML-Agents/Examples/FoodCollector).

How does the agent get information about the position of the food on the map? The food is spawned at a random point, so in order to track it, you need to know the position of each one. Can someone explain?

Comment: The documentation states how the observation is gathered here https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/develop/docs/Learning-Environment-Examples.md do you have a specific part of it you don't understand?